# Java EE class loading standard

Tags: architecture, jakarta-ee, classloader

WebSphere comes with parent last and parent first. Is this Java EE compliant? Is this supported by all application servers that are Java EE 5 compliant?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I did my own research (going through the specs and few blogs) and below is what I've figured

**EAR**

The spec DOES NOT define or mandate how the class loaders should work within an EAR. It however defines that

1. there SHOULD be per thread context class loader for runtime loading of classes
2. there MIGHT be a hierarchical class loading mechanism for resolving classes (app server vendors are free to implement whichever way they choose to)
3. the top level class loader (WAR/EAR) MAY delegate to the low level class loaders (like Bootstrap, extension etc). This is in compliance with J2SE class loader delegation model (PARENT_FIRST in WAS)

**WAR**

Servlet specification defines and mandates the support of a PARENT_LAST (i.e. WAR/web-inf/classes and WAR/web-inf/lib take precedence over the libraries that come with the app server) class loading model. But this is just for WAR modules. The Servlet spec diverges from the standard J2SE delegation model of PARENT_FIRST in this case.

**Reference**

Spec: Servlet 2.3, Section: 9.7.2 Web Application Classloader

Spec: Java EE 5, Section: EE.6.2.4.7 Context Class Loader

**App Server specifics**

Interestingly, though, it appears most major app servers support some mechanism of turning off delegation to isolate the application from the app server if necessary (because of conflicts or otherwise):  WebSphere - "parent-last", GlassFish - `<class-loader delegate="false">`, JBoss - `java2ParentDelegation=false`, Geronimo - `<java2-delgation-model>false</java2-delegation-model>`

Comment: Nice one. In Glassfish it's btw `<class-loader delegate="false" />` in `sun-web.xml` to turn off delegation. See also http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3659/beadf?l=en&a=view (picture) and http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1752/beade?l=en&a=view

Answer (score 0):

Good information. I was researching the same question and came to similar conclusions. One question still remains is, is it recommended to go with Parent Last option? I would think it will be since your application is more portable; you are not dependent on the Appserver libs. You achieve application isolation.
I don't see people recommending one way or the other. Did you come across any such best practice recommendations ?

Comment: "I would think it will be since your application is more portable; you are not dependent on the Appserver libs. You achieve application isolation. " ---- It might or might not work as there is no standard mandated by spec. For e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097567/jboss-and-different-versions-of-hibernate

Comment: Here is 1 more scenario with trying to use JSF 2.0 with WAS 7 and using PARENT_LAST for EAR and WAR. Still WAS trying to use myfaces impl that it comes bundled with. Ofcourse he was able to solve it by updating the EL impl to use but the point is that you cannot guarantee everything to work even if you switch delegation policy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214373/websphere-7-jsf-2-0-and-classloaders