# How to deal with classpath conflict

Tags: java, glassfish, guava, glassfish-embedded

In my project, I'm using both glassfish-embedded 3.1.1 and the guava lib... The problem is that glassfish comes with the old implementation of guava (ie google-collections)...

This results in NoSuchMethodError at runtime, for example when using Lists.reverse(), or Sets.newIdentityHashSet() which were introduced later in guava.

I don't find any solution to solve this... (the only one is to manually trash the com/google classes directory in the glassfish jar...)

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately, not at all...

Comment: In case you care, I found an embedded v4 build and the classpath issue went away. You can find the build here: http://grepcode.com/snapshot/maven.java.net/content/groups/promoted/org.glassfish.main.extras/glassfish-embedded-all/4.0.1-b01

Comment: @JagWire I'm not working with Glassfish anymore, but it's a very good thing to know they have fix this. I will update Kevin's anwser with your link. Thanks a lot for that :)

Comment: I have a similar problem, not with glassfish, but with some other jar library from my poms. Unfortunately I have a lot of libraries in my poms. Can someone tell me how to track down which jar is causing a conflict? I have no idea how to do it. All I know is my code crashes when I try to edit my guava in my poms to higher than 19.0 - and I want to use functionality from 21 in my project! but can't as long as this problem persists...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glassfish should never have included com.google classes in their own jar. That was an error.

UPDATE[@sly7_7]: It seems like glassfish does not include guava in their own jar anymore, but it depends on the guava artifact instead. This should resolve the problem.
Thanks to @JagWire for pointing this.

Comment: That's what I think... and it's the same thing for slf4j :(

Answer (score 7):

You can overcome this be specifying the below. Read the [Delegation section of the Class Loaders chapter.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beade/index.html)

```
<class-loader delegate="false" />
```

Check this SO post for class loading in Java EE apps in general: [Java EE class loading standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199158/jee-j2ee-classloading-standard)

Comment: We try it, but it does not work in our case... This results in ClassCastException (probably due to same classes loaded by different classloaders)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the error go away by using the following Glassfish v4 build:

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/maven.java.net/content/groups/promoted/org.glassfish.main.extras/glassfish-embedded-all/4.0.1-b01

Might be worth taking a look.