# Java EE and Java SE classloading

Tags: java, classloader

The difference that I read on the Internet between Java EE and Java SE classloading is that

> In Java SE, a classloader delegates the classloading to its parent
>   classloader and then tries to load the class itself
>
> However, In Java EE, a classloader first tries to load the class itself and then
>   delegate the classloading of that class to its parent classloader.

**Kindly validate my understanding.**

Also, why is it designed like that in Java EE (Any advantages of keeping it like this.)

This is the link where I heard this [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8sQw3pGJzM]

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199158/java-ee-class-loading-standard (but if you found a place that says the order described above is mandated, please include the link.  the SO answer seems to disagree).

Comment: @Gamb I have already gone through this link. But didn't get the idea. Still there is a confusion. BTW thanks for sharing the link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alright then,

A common application has 3 standard classloaders:

1. Bootstrap Classloader
2. Extensions Classloader
3. System-Classpath Classloader

So far, so good. Now, this works for a *single* application running alone and free.

But what happens when you say *J2EE*? You have *multiple applications* running on the same place, so you have to figure out a way to prevent them from *stumbling on each other*. That's where these extra classloaders come into play.

Think about a server instance. There's a JBoss with two deployed EARs. What would happen if there were to be *conflicting classes between applications*? They're ok on their own particular context but as a whole they're inconsistent.

These extra classloaders are introduced in an application-wise way to *ensure the isolation between them*. Classloaders below *System-Classpath Classloader* recognize a class only if it is specified in the manifest file for one of its childs.

In J2SE, the three basic classloaders work in a parent-child relationship based on three principles:

1. Delegation: If a class is not loaded (cache), the request is delegated to its parent. This goes on until the top of the hierarchy (*Bootstrap* classloader) who loads basic J2SE related classes (i.e. `Integer`, `ArrayList`, amongst others). This is what you reference in your question: **A classloader delegates the loading until the top of the hierarchy, then each classloader tries to load the class if its parent couldn't find it, until someone loads it. Otherwise: ClassNotFound.**
2. Visibility: Classes loaded by a parent classloader are visible to its children, not the other way around.
3. Uniqueness: If a parent classloader loads a class, a children will never reload it.

> In Java SE, a classloader delegates the classloading to its parent classloader and then tries to load the class itself.

True, due to the principles explained above.

There's no determined classloader structure in J2EE (a vendor has "poetic license" to implement it), but they kind of follow a hierarchy. In this case, the *System-classpath* classloader loads the main application: The server. The server libraries (its classes, more specifically) are available, then, to every application due to the *visibility principle*.

Down there, the applications have particular classloader structures, but as a whole they are **different** children of the *System-classpath classloader*. Each application loads its related and particular classes (both application and libraries).

The loading here is not propagated to the parents outside the application context. Why? because if the *System-classpath* classloader were to load the applications as usual, the class of every application would be visible to others due to the visibility principle, completely breaking the isolation between themselves. So:

> However, In Java EE, a classloader first tries to load the class itself and then delegate the classloading of that class to its parent classloader.

This is partly true, but I'd rather limit this affirmation to the context of an application and leave out the Java related classes, that are indeed loaded by the top level classloaders.

Long story short: It's not a straightforward process but I wouldn't go as far as to say J2EE handles the classloading the opposite way around of J2SE.

Comment: My question is somewhat different, I already know about J2SE classloading but is it different from J2EE classloading or not. That is what my question is. Thanks.

Comment: @John I understood your question, that's why I described the difference between both of them. Of course they are different, in a J2EE context you have to ensure application isolation. Being completely strict, they are different because they handle the classloading in a different way (J2EE has more classloaders involved and the handling is done differently).

Comment: Ok thats nice, But nowhere you talked about the order of classloading in J2SE and J2EE, what I am trying to ask mainly in the question.

Comment: @John You asked: *Kindly validate my understanding* and: *Also, why is it designed like that in Java EE (Any advantages of keeping it like this.)*. I tried to fuse both answers into one by describing the processes. No worries, I'll put it in simpler and more explicit terms, then.

Comment: Is there any classes that are being shared between System-classpath classloader and the application specific classloader?

Comment: Would you please explain this line "I'd rather limit this affirmation to the context of an application and leave out the Java related classes"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35534/discussion-between-john-and-gamb)

Answer (score 1):

I think [Java EE class loading standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199158/java-ee-class-loading-standard) will help you on your way. As far as I know there is no mandated way of classloading for standard Java. For WebApps (WARs) however, it is specified that the classloading is parent-last.

Comment: So You are agreeing with what i said.. the behavior of classloaders is opposite in J2EE and J2SE.

Comment: Well in practice yes, except that the EE spec doesn't mandate anything it's just that it's implemented that way.