# Jboss WAR deploys succesfully but EAR fails classNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss, ear

I have a web application where i use resteasy and spring. It deploys successfully
when using the WAR but fails when I deploy the EAR.

This is the parent pom.xml :
`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ro</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>Mywar</module>
        <module>Myear</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

`

This is the WAR pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ro</groupId>
  <artifactId>mywar</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>mywar Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <parent>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <groupId>ro</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <build>
    <finalName>mywar</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

This is the EAR pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <groupId>ro</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>myear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ro</groupId>
            <artifactId>mywar</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <!-- configuring the ear plugin -->
                <configuration>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>ro</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mywar</artifactId>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When i deploy the EAR to jboss i get the following error:

```
15:48:18,266 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-2) Failed to define class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener in Module "deployment.myear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/spring/SpringContextLoaderListener (Module "deployment.myear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener from [Module "deployment.myear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is related to the different strategy of weblogic classloading. You can try force prefering the jars in your web-inf by configuring the weblogic.xml. Have a look [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0551.html). You can also specify the classloading order. Moreover to better understand how classloding in an app-server differs from standard java classloading mechanism I can suggest you reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210389/java-ee-and-java-se-classloading) and [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/programming/classloading.html).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution that problem, here: 
[ClassNotFoundException for included dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675845/classnotfoundexception-for-included-dependency/39687000#39687000)

I believe it can help you.